# JavaScript IF statement problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a problem writing an if statement, due to my lack of programing skills.

there's the code :

```
   $("div.footerMenu li div.onScreen").click( 
  function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); return false; } 
);
```

Inside this `div` I have simple `<a></a>` links. And the problem is, when i click on that link, nothing happens. I'm trying to make a function, that would not execute that `function(e)` if the target of `.click` would be an `<a></a>` tag. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Just so you know, `return false` is the same as doing both `e.stopPropagation` and `e.preventDefault`.

Comment: @Jonathon Bolster: I agree. But does that also apply to bubbling when using delegation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that because you're link is inside the div, your code is blocking the click event, hence why nothing happens. You could try this:

```
$("div.footerMenu li div.onScreen").click(function(e) { 
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a') {
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false; 
    }
});
```

I'm using .toLowerCase() because I'm not 100% the tagName will always be uppercase in all browsers. Just a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and here is the solution that works :)

```
$("div.footerMenu li div.onScreen").click(function(e) { 
    if( !( $(e.target).is('a') ) ) 
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); return false; 
    } 
);
```

Comment: i have up-voted your answer because testing for an "a" is much simpler done here using "is('a')"

Comment: Thank you, I hope the Szymon finds this one helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yup, very easy

```
if (e.target.nodeName !== "A") {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the node has tagName == 'A'

```
if (this.tagName == 'A')
```

"this" should reference to the node being clicked, otherwise lookup e.target or e.targetSrc (don't know the jQuery equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an element, only events it will be running. But not events atached on parent elements.
You need to change your selector to match all child elements.

$("div.footerMenu li div.onScreen > *")
$("div.footerMenu li div.onScreen > a")

Answer (score 0):

Rather than check if target was an `a` (to me, it's a bit messy), I'd prefer to separate it out and handle the links separately. By using `e.stopPropagation` *only*, you'll be able to click the link and have whatever action you want on it as well as preventing the event from bubbling up to the div.

```
$("div").click(function(e){
    alert('You clicked me, I am the div!');
});

$("div a").click(function(e){
    // Allows the link to be clicked but prevents
    // the event from bubbling up to the div
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/s2TxS/